# Normal size of alias folder

Tags: folders, alias

I just delated an alias folder and I saw that the size in the bin was around 1.3 Mbit is this normal? Shouldn't be around few Kbyte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks about right to me, just tested with a random folder, made an alias, threw it in the trash...

[image]

Comparatively, I tested against a small jpg image. Image was 273KB, alias is 957KB